# DataTables Editable Delete

Tags: jquery, datatables, jeditable

I've add DataTables Editable to my table to able to add and delete some rows.
The add part works great, but I'm having some problem with the delete part, because I can't select the rows.

By what I've seen in the example all I've to do is to add the delete URL, something like this:

.makeEditable({sDeleteURL: "/DeleteURL"});

But that dosent make my rows selectable so I can delete anthing.

My full code is:

```
$(function () {
    var oTable = $('.table-@Model.Numero').dataTable(
        {
            "oLanguage": { "sUrl": "/LanguageURL" },
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sClass": "center-col", "aTargets": ['align-center-col'] },
                { "sClass": "read_only", "aTargets": ['read-only-col'] },
                { "sClass": "small-width-col", "aTargets": ['small-col'] }],
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '/DataURL',
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({ "name": "Numero", "value": $(this).find("#Numero").val() });
                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                });
            }
        }).makeEditable({
            sAddNewRowFormId: 'form-@Model.Numero',
            sAddNewRowButtonId: 'btn-@Model.Numero',
            btnDeleteRow: 'btn-del-@Model.Numero',
            sAddURL: "/AddURL",
            sDeleteURL: "/DeleteURL"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've personally been playing around with getting the datatables delete function to work for one of my projects.

What I've found is I needed to include the `jquery-ui.js` script in the head of the document.

I also discovered that you need to format your table rows like this. `<tr id="1">` so that datatables can automatically grab the correct id # from the selected row and pass it on to your php page for further processing.

Datatables can automatically add an id to each table row through the use of `DT_RowId` special property.

If you have set up datatables to use server side implementation, then you can include `DT_RowId` in the JSON data returned from the server in response to the ajax request .

For example JSON format:

```
{ 
 "sEcho": 1,
 "iTotalRecords": "1",
 "iTotalDisplayRecords": "1",
 "aaData": [
  {
    "DT_RowId": "1",
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
"version": "4",
    "grade": "X"
  }
 ]
}
```

Here is my example mockup code. Server side implementation isn't included with this example I'm just using the example source objects.txt that came with datatables for an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
    <script src="examples/examples_support/jquery.jeditable.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/media/js/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <script src="datatables/media/js/jquery.datatables.editable.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "datatables/media/css/demo_table.css";
        @import "datatables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css";
        @import "examples/examples_support/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";
    </style> 
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var anOpen = [];
            var sImageUrl = "/datatables/examples/examples_support/";

            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "/datatables/examples/ajax/sources/objects.txt",
                "aoColumns": 
                [
                    {
                       "mDataProp": null,
                       "sClass": "control center",
                       "sDefaultContent": '<img src="'+sImageUrl+'details_open.png'+'">'
                    },
                    { "mDataProp": "engine" },
                    { "mDataProp": "browser" },
                    { "mDataProp": "grade" }
                ]
            }).makeEditable({
                sDeleteURL: "DeleteData.php",
                //Converts to JQuery UI button (full list of options on http://jqueryui.com/demos/button)
                oDeleteRowButtonOptions:
                {
                    label: "Remove",
                    icons: {primary:'ui-icon-trash'}
                },
                //Additional Paramaters can be sent for processing...
                oDeleteParameters:
                {
                    action:"delete_dt_projects_record",
                    dtSecurity:"9999999999"
                }
            });
            //For Expandable Collapsible Rows
            $('#example td.control').live( 'click', function () {

                var nTr = this.parentNode;
                //var projID = $(this).closest("td").next().text();
                //console.log(projID);
                //console.log(anOpen);
                //console.log(nTr);
                var i = $.inArray( nTr, anOpen );
                //console.log(i);
                if ( i === -1 ) 
                {
                    $('img', this).attr( 'src', sImageUrl+"details_close.png" );
                    var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
                    $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();

                    anOpen.push( nTr );
                }
                else 
                {
                $('img', this).attr( 'src', sImageUrl+"details_open.png" );
                $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp( function () 
                    {
                        oTable.fnClose( nTr );
                        anOpen.splice( i, 1 );
                    });
                }
            });
            function fnFormatDetails( oTable, nTr )
            {
              var oData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
              var sOut =
                '<div class="innerDetails">'+
                  '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                    '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+oData.engine+'</td></tr>'+
                    '<tr><td>Browser:</td><td>'+oData.browser+'</td></tr>'+
                    '<tr><td>Platform:</td><td>'+oData.platform+'</td></tr>'+
                    '<tr><td>Version:</td><td>'+oData.version+'</td></tr>'+
                    '<tr><td>Grade:</td><td>'+oData.grade+'</td></tr>'+
                  '</table>'+
                '</div>';
              return sOut;
            }
        });

    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <div style="width:900px">
    <div class="add_delete_toolbar">
        <button id="btnDeleteRow">Delete</button>
    </div>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

NOTE You may have to change the script and Style URL paths to where yours are located in order to see a working example.

Update: You also need to manually include this anywhere in your HTML source.

```
<button id="btnDeleteRow">Delete</button>
```